# How to Schedule jobs based on virtual managed clock?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, scheduling, scheduler

I'm working on a Spring web application analyzing events flow from connected objects.

This flow is not in real time (data are reported by packets every X minutes) but events are ordered by detection time.

I'd like to trigger jobs between two events in my flow at a given time.

In other words i'd like a lib like Quartz or other that allows me to use a virtual clock (other than the system one) that move in the same speed as my events flow.

In my use case I have indoor presences and door opening.

In one of the situation I'd like to start counting presences 30 secondes after door opening and stop counting 5 minutes after door opening.

The problem is, I have already received events 30 seconds after door opening and maybe I will receive event 4 minutes after the opening in 10 minutes.

EDIT: I don’t want to schedule task according to server time but I want be able to manage clock myself.

Example: I receive an event and I change the virtual clock to the event creation date and if a task is schedule before the new virtual clock it will be launched.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve specifically?

Comment: In my use case I have indoor presences and door opening, in one of the situation I'd like to start counting presences 30 secondes after door opening and stop counting 5 minutes after door opening.

The problem is, I have already received events 30 seconds after door opening and maybe I will receive event 4 minutes after the opening in 10 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, there is no lib that does what I want so I implemented it myself in a really basic way (but sufficient for my use case).

Thanks for every one who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Spring Scheduler (if I correctly understand what you want to achieve) : [Spring Scheduler Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Spring Scheduler is based on system clock, I need a clock that I can manage synchronized with my event flow

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something as simple as [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) could do the job.
When the event comes in create a timer for 30 seconds. This timer will trigger the commencement of counting presences, and it will create a timer for 4.5 minutes. When the callback comes in for the second timer counting presences stops.

Comment: Timer is based on system clock. If I schedule a timer in 30 secondes, i will skip events that will be processed in 10 ms but are 30 secondes after the door opening.

Comment: Anything in a computer will be based on the system clock. Unless you use some network time service, which itself will be based on a system clock. I think you're trying to solve your problem in the wrong way. Maybe sit down and analyse what exactly you need to happen and how you can solve it.

Comment: As I said, packets are received by packets, one packet contains 2 or 3 minutes of data and 1 packet will bee processed in one batch

Comment: I think the word "scheduling" is badly chosen, I just want some code to be called at some point inside of my batch processing.

Comment: And you want there to be a guard at a set time interval? That's what my answer will provide.